# Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL column "user2" does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, postgresql-9.5

My Django views.py passes a email address to a python function. The
python function queries a PostgreSQL table using a where clause. The
where clause is equal to the email address that was passed in
(someuser). My goal is to retrieve the userid value for this email
address. But I get an error message telling me that there is no column
called  "user2" which is correct (there is not). But why does the
select see that as an existing column?

I print the email out only to verify that it got passed in. someuser
for select=  user2@gmail.com

> Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL
>   column "user2" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT userid from accounts_user
>   WHERE email = user2@gmail.c...

I have ran this locally on my Windows 10 box as well as on AWS Cloud9
with the same result. It tells me that no column exists that begins
with the email address up to the '@' sign.

```
import psycopg2
def get_userid(someuser): 
try:
      connection = psycopg2.connect(bla, bla")
      cursor = connection.cursor()
      print("someuser for select= ", someuser)
      postgreSQL_select_Query = ("""SELECT userid from accounts WHERE email = %s;""" %(someuser)) 
      cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)  
      mobile_records = cursor.fetchall() 
      for row in mobile_records:
         print("userid = ", row[0], )
   except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error :
      print ("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
   finally:
      if(connection):
        cursor.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_userid()
```

table has this:

```
 id |         email          | userid 
----+------------------------+--------  
 18 | user2@gmail.com        | u48923
```

I expect to get the userid of "u48923" after running the select.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the following

`postgreSQL_select_Query = ("""SELECT userid from accounts WHERE email = '%s';""" %(someuser))`

But a better way is to use the built in functionality of psycopg2 and write it as follows

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT userid from accounts WHERE email = %s;""", (someuser,))
```

Psycopg2 [Documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

Comment: --I tried both methods but now I get:
Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL can't adapt type 'User'
It must be referring to the Django User class (below) but how does that 
effect my query? 

class User(AbstractBaseUser):     # this is a custom user class 
    email       =models.EmailField(max_length=160, unique=True)     # this is NOW 
    userid      =models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

Comment: print(someuser) and see what the value is or try converting it to a string

Comment: --my source code:
someuser = str(someuser)  # convert to string
print("someuser= ", someuser)
postgreSQL_select_Query = "SELECT userid FROM accounts_user WHERE email = someuser"    
--displays:
someuser=  user2@gmail.com  # in python shell it shows single quotes around it but not in console
Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL column "someuser" does not exist
--but the userid is returned when hardcoded like this:
postgreSQL_select_Query = "SELECT userid FROM accounts_user WHERE email = 'user2@gmail.com' "

Comment: Have you tried:    cursor.execute("""SELECT userid from accounts WHERE email = %s;""", (str(someuser),))

Answer (score 0):

```
def getEmail(someuser):    print("received someuser in 'run_select' from views.py= ", someuser)    try:

      connection = psycopg2.connect(user="my user",
                                  password="xxxxxx",
                                  host="127.0.0.1",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="my_db")
      cursor = connection.cursor()
      print("again someuser for select= ", someuser)
      someuser = str(someuser)  # convert to string or you get: Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL can't adapt type 'User'
      print("someuser= ", someuser)
      cursor.execute("""SELECT userid from accounts_user WHERE email = %s""", (someuser,))
      print("Selecting rows from c9_max_forms_kw using cursor.fetchall")
      mobile_records = cursor.fetchall() 
      print("Print each row and it's columns values")
      for row in mobile_records:
         print("Id = ", row[0], )
         #print("email = ", row[5])
         #print("userid  = ", row[9], "\n")    # should be "u48923"
         #save = ''.join(row[9])               # convert this tuple to a string    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error :
      print ("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)    finally:
      #closing database connection.
      if(connection):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")    return someuser
```

Joshua is the man. The string conversion was the key. The error given without it doesn't seem to make sense to me.  Best to all. Ken.